# How to document a JSON parameter in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, json, parameters, jsdoc

I've just started learning [`JSDoc`](https://jsdoc.app/) and the first stumbling block I've come across is how to indicate a **function parameter** which *must* be valid `JSON`.

I'm looking at the documentation for [`@param`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) and I can't see:

- `@param {JSON}`

What's the correct approach in `JSDoc` to indicate a **function parameter** which *must* be valid `JSON`?

*(Surely it's not right to use `@param {string}`, is it?)*

Comment: JSON text *is* a string. JsDoc has no syntax to document the format of strings, you need to use the textual description of the parameter for that.

Comment: @Bergi Perhaps I can deploy something like: `@typedef {string} JSON` and then use `@param {JSON}`? (See: https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of any other answers so far, I'm going to go with defining `JSON` as a **type** at the top of the javascript file, like this:

```
/**
 * Define JSON
 * @typedef {string} JSON
 */
```

and then, later on, use the `JSON` type in my function definitions etc.

See the line starting with `@param` below:

```
/**
 * Compresses JSON data
 * @function compressJSON
 * @param {JSON} myJSON - any valid JSON
 * @returns {string} a compressed version of the JSON input
 */
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html